Manually changing selected state of material3 NavigationBarItem in Jetpack Compose
I'm following this tutorial to create a bottom navigation bar. Here is the example code:
val navController = rememberNavController()
Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigation {
            val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
            val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
            items.forEach { screen ->
                BottomNavigationItem(
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                    label = { Text(stringResource(screen.resourceId)) },
                    selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                            // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                            // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                            // on the back stack as users select items
                            popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                            // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                            // reselecting the same item
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                            restoreState = true
                        }
                    },
                )
            }
        }
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Profile.route,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
    ) {
        composable(Screen.Profile.route) { Profile(navController) }
        composable(Screen.FriendsList.route) { FriendsList(navController) }
    }
}

I'm now looking for a way to modify the select state of a BottomNavigationItem programmatically from e.g. the Profile composable at the bottom of the source example.
Using the navController to navigate between the different composables is simple since there is the navController.navigate() function. But changing the seleted state of the items in the BottomNavigation is tough.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You have everything already there: Navigate to where you want to go with navController.navigate() and the bottom bar will automatically update to highlight the new destination.

The code above actually works correct as you mentioned. I compared the wrong property of my screen in it.route == screen.route.

So, am I right to assume that this question can be closed then? By the way, when you want to use Material 3 as your title suggests you should replace the Material 2 composables BottomNavigation and BottomNavigationItem by their Material 3 counterparts NavigationBar and NavigationBarItem. It should largely work the same.

Thanks for clearification, I used the composables you mentioned. Yes, question can be closed.
